# The set {f analytic in the open unit disk and $f' \in H^1$} is a Banach-space

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that the set 
$\{f \text{ analytic on } \mathbb{D} \text{ and }f' \in H^1\}$ equipped with the norm
$\|f\| = \|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{H^1}$ is a Banach space. I am aware of the fact that $f$ has got an absolutly convergent series representation, but I do not know how to continue. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. Say $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in that norm. Then because $H^\infty$ and $H^1$ are complete we have $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $f_n'\to g$ in $H^1$. Hence $f_n'\to g$ uniformly on compact sets, and alos $f_n'\to f'$ uniformly on compact sets. So $g=f'$, hence $||f_n-f||\to0$.